Finding probabilities of each value in all categorical columns across a dataframe
My question is nearly identical to Finding frequency of each value in all categorical columns across a dataframe, but I need the probabilities, instead of the frequencies. We can use the same example dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sub_code': ['CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE02', 'CSE03', 'CSE04',
                  'CSE05', 'CSE06'],
     'stud_level': [101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101],
     'grade': ['STA', 'STA', 'PSA', 'STA', 'STA', 'SSA', 'PSA', 'QSA']})

I tried adapting this answer in the following way:
out = (df.select_dtypes(object)
       .melt(var_name="Variable", value_name="Class")
       .value_counts(dropna=False, normalize=True)
       .reset_index(name="Probability")
       .sort_values(by=['Variable', 'Class'], ascending=[True, True])
       .reset_index(drop=True))

However, the code doesn't work, because the sum of the class probabilities for each variable is not 1. What am I doing wrong?

Could you add your desired output? For reference, [mre].

I think I found a solution, but I'm terribly lacking on stats vocabulary so I'm not sure if it's correct, but if I saw the desired output I'd be confident enough to post it.

IIUC, you need to to groupby on 'Variable' after melting. This will give you the probabilities for each value in 'Class' in relation to each value in 'Variable'.
out = (
    df.select_dtypes(object)
    .melt(var_name="Variable", value_name="Class")
    .groupby("Variable")  # add this line
    .value_counts(dropna=False, normalize=True)
    .reset_index(name="Probability")
    .sort_values(by=["Variable", "Class"], ascending=[True, True])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

   Variable  Class  Probability
0     grade    PSA        0.250
1     grade    QSA        0.125
2     grade    SSA        0.125
3     grade    STA        0.500
4  sub_code  CSE01        0.375
5  sub_code  CSE02        0.125
6  sub_code  CSE03        0.125
7  sub_code  CSE04        0.125
8  sub_code  CSE05        0.125
9  sub_code  CSE06        0.125

